# Using jQuery is it possible to combine selector assignment with a change event reassignment at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var gsaForm = $("form#search"), 
    gsaSite = $(":input[name=site]", gsaForm).val();

$(":input[name=site]", gsaForm).on("change", function(e) {
  gsaSite = $(this).val();
});
```

I'd really like to clean this up (looks ugly to me). There must be a way to assign gsaSite once but cover both my bases. Is it possible?

Comment: You're going to need to improve your question. I, at least, have no idea what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is a variable that is always equal to the value of a form input.

You're better off assigning a variable to the input, and then just use `.val()` whenever you need the value:

```
var gsaField = $(':input[name="site"]',gsaForm);

gsaField.val();
```

The processing time of calling `.val()` each time you want the value isn't large enough to bother attaching a `change` event to the field just to reassign a variable.